# How can I install Ubuntu on a IBM ThinkPad with a USB?

Tags: usb, thinkpad

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install Ubuntu to a USB key?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key)

I would like to know the steps to follow to install Ubuntu on a IBM ThinkPad with a USB please. I would like to replace completly with Ubuntu (No windows).

Comment: Refer this http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your laptop can boot from usb. Some computers have a special boot menu by pressing F2 for example to be able to do this.

Then you need to have a bootable USB:

If you have Windows, download Unetbootin and install it. With this you can create a bootable pendrive.

If you have another Ubuntu computer, use "startup disk creator".
When ready, you can boot your pc from the usb stick. Be patient, it might be slow.

On the desktop youĺl find an "Install Ubuntu" link.

Follow instructions.